# Multiply all values from 2 to 10 using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm really new to R and I have zero programming experience. This is all really confusing to me, and I'm working on an assignment for class right now that's got me very stressed. I feel like it's probably obvious and easy but I need some help.

The question is asking me to "Multiply all integer values from 2 to 10 using a for loop, and print the product named 'p' only once at the end"

So I want to get R to do 2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9x10 and then get R to print p = 3,628,800 but using a for loop, basically. That I get. But I'm not sure how.

I've been trying for an hour or more by now, typing things in and googling for help, looking on reddit, and here but I'm lost. I'm not looking for someone to just type the for loop in either so I can turn in my assignment, I actually want an explanation so I can understand and try to learn this.

I'm thinking I have to figure out some way to get R to multiply the first two numbers, then multiply that by the next, and so on. But I have no idea how to do this. I have tried a couple things but they are nowhere near what I need, so I'm not even going to bother putting them here.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

We cannstart by declaring a variable to use for the result. We can make this the number 1, since we are going to multiply it by all the other numbers between 2 and 10.

```
result <- 1
```

Then we do the the loop. We go through all the numbers from 2 to 10 using
the syntax `for(i in 2:10)`, which means "do the following for each value
between 2 and 10, using *i* as the stand-in for each number". We just multiply `result` by `i` and store the result back to `result` each time.

```r
for(i in 2:10) {
  result <- result * i
}
```

Now we can print the result:

```
print(result)
#> [1] 3628800
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you! I knew there had to be some way to get it to multiply it be the answer, but it was giving errors since I had never defined 'result'.  Is there any way to get the for loop to print the ending value of p, or is that something I have to do afterwards as you have? The wording on the assignment question makes it seem like it has to be all in the for loop but maybe not? Thanks again.

Comment: @zinger001 it would make more sense and be far more conventional to do it after the loop. To do it inside the loop you would need to add the line `if(i == 10) print(result)` inside the loop